# How do I check for UTF-8 encoded data (bytes) in python 2.4

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.4

In higher versions of python i can do:

```
isinstance(s_out, bytes)
```

There is no 'bytes' in python2.4. Is there an equivalent of doing this in python2.4 which also works for all other python versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys

if sys.version_info < (2, 7):
    bytes = str


if isinstance(s_out, bytes):
```

I really don't know the context but wouldn't it better to upgrade at least to python 2.7 and not lose time trying to make code python 2.4 compatible.

I do not know the target systems and the OS, but could imagine that it is possible to install a more recent python and invest the time to make the code work with newer pythons.

Comment: Given Python 2.7 support lapses completely (no more fixes, even security fixes) at the end of this year, even upgrading to 2.7 is not much of a solution, though it's better than nothing.

Comment: Works, thanks. The long term fix is to upgrade the python. For short term needed to make some package backward compatible to prevent bleeding.